# How can i get more precise error message with oozie?

Tags: java, logging, hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I'm looking for a way to have more information about job errors with Oozie. In fact, I can't use the Oozie console. I have only access to the putty console and see the job status (running, ok, failed...).

When a job is killed, I cannot find where the problem is: in my mapReduce java classes and on which lines? or in my XML files? etc.

Have you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this with your putty console?

```
oozie job -oozie http://<oozie address:port>/oozie info <job-id> verbose
```